# Passing C++ callbacks to matlab engine as function handles without using mex

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2015, mex, function-handle

My project is in C++. I want to use matlab optimization `nonlinsq` through matlab engine by "eval". I want to pass a function I wrote in C++ in the format of

```
    void func(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[])
```

to matlab as a function handle without compiling it to mex.

I tried following [Passing C/C++ callbacks into the matlab engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068558/passing-c-c-callbacks-into-the-matlab-engine/13759101#13759101) for creating a mxArray and then pass it to matlab workspace:

```
    mxArray *fh = mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(func);
    engPutVariable(engine, "func", fh);
    mxDestroyArray(fh);
```

but the program crashed on the first line with access violation. In the call stack the last call before the violation was 
"mclmcrrt8_5.dll!000000000031dacd() Unknown"

What is the problem?..

Comment: Please let me know if I got you straight: you want the MATLAB engine to *interpret* your C++ source code? That's not going to happen.

Comment: I think you got it right. But I found some links as the one I posted to some solutions I couldn't make work. You say it can only get a sort of dll? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking the MATLAB run-time engine to *interpret* the C/C++ code is the wrong way to do it (and I'm sure is impossible at this moment). The post you're referring to assumes that the C/C++ code is compiled into a shared object or a dynamically linked library. The `mex` function itself requires a supported compiler that can be invoked in order to create the `.mex` file.

**TLDR:** MATLAB cannot interpret C/C++ code.